# Install ARM-CrossCompiler with support for C++11

Tags: debian, cross-compilation

I spent over 5 hours searching the internet on how to install an ARM-CrossCompiler on a Debian Wheezy system on an Intel processor.

I have found emdebian which gave me a working CrossCompiler but it is version gcc-4.4, which does not yet have the C++11 standard which I desperately need.

How can I have a new version of a CrossCompiler?

Comment: Any chance you could use a Jessie system instead? It has better support for recent cross-compilers...

Comment: @StephenKitt No. This is not possible...